# Tk Python combobox in loop get the data selected

Tags: python-3.x, loops, tkinter, combobox, dropdown

I want to show in a loop a dropdown list and capture the data selected. I have the below code, but even printing it is not working.. Could someone help me please?

So let's say that on the 1st screen I chose a, b, c in that order, then on the 2nd I chose d, c, a in that order; and on the last I chose a, d, c in that order, I would like my final list to be:

```
lb_sel = [['a', 'b', 'c'],['d', 'c', 'a'],['a', 'd', 'c']]

from tkinter import filedialog, messagebox, ttk, constants
from tkinter import *


def DropDown(argslist,index):
    var = StringVar()
    c= ttk.Combobox(root,width=40)
    c['values'] = argslist
    c.textvariable=var
    c.current(0)
    c.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>",choice_sel)
    c.grid(row=index-1, column=1,padx=(15,25))
    c.index=index

nb_choice = 3
has_choice = True
lst = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
lb_sel = [[] for i in range(nb_choice)]

lst.insert(0,'Select a choice')
for i in range(nb_choice):
    root = Tk()
    root.focus_force()
    root.title('Choices')
    labl1 = ttk.Label(text = 'Select the first choice of N.' + str(i+1))
    labl1.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
    labl2 = ttk.Label(text = 'Select the second choice of N.' + str(i+1))
    labl2.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
    labl3 = ttk.Label(text = 'Select the third choice of N.' + str(i+1))
    labl3.grid(row = 2, column = 0)
    def choice_sel():
        print(lb1.get())
    lb1 = DropDown(lst,1)
    lb2 = DropDown(lst,2)
    lb3 = DropDown(lst,3)
    
    exit_but = Button(root, text = 'OK', command = lambda: choice_sel, height = 3, width = 5)
    exit_but.grid(row = 2, column = 2)
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code makes the work:

```
from tkinter import filedialog, messagebox, ttk, constants
from tkinter import *

def choice_sel(index, *args, **kwargs):
    lb_sel[index-1].append(args[0].widget.get())

def DropDown(argslist,index):
    var = StringVar()
    c= ttk.Combobox(root,width=40)
    c['values'] = argslist
    c.textvariable=var
    c.current(0)
    c.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>",lambda event, index=index: choice_sel(index, event))
    c.grid(row=index-1, column=1,padx=(15,25))
    c.index=index

nb_choice = 3
has_choice = True
lst = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
lb_sel = [[] for i in range(nb_choice)]

lst.insert(0,'Select a choice')
for i in range(nb_choice):
    root = Tk()
    root.focus_force()
    root.title('Choices')
    labl1 = ttk.Label(text = 'Select the first choice of N.' + str(i+1))
    labl1.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
    labl2 = ttk.Label(text = 'Select the second choice of N.' + str(i+1))
    labl2.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
    labl3 = ttk.Label(text = 'Select the third choice of N.' + str(i+1))
    labl3.grid(row = 2, column = 0)
    DropDown(lst,1)
    DropDown(lst,2)
    DropDown(lst,3)
    
    exit_but = Button(root, text = 'OK', command = choice_sel, height = 3, width = 5)
    exit_but.grid(row = 2, column = 2)
    root.mainloop()
```

Result after pressing 'a' and 'b' on the first dropdown and 'b' on the second one:

```
lb_sel = [['a', 'b'], ['b'], []]
```

The things I have changed to make it work have been:

1. Set `choice_sel` outside the for loop and add `*args` and `*kwargs` arguments since it was used on two different places of the code, one of which was necessary to pass the `event` argument. This was actually causing an error during run-time.
2. Pass the `index` argument to the function too to know which was the pressed dropdown.
3. Get the value of the combobox with the method `widget.get()`.
4. Remove the return variable from function `DropDown` since it does not return any value.

Please bear in mind that you should probably reset/save the variable `lb_sel` when you close the main window to go to the next iteration of the for-loop.

Side note: It is preferable to use `TopLevel` instead of creating multiple instances of `Tk`.

Comment: Hi David, thank you very much for the help. I am new with Tk and obviously have more to learn! But I tried to run it but then I got the following error: `Exception in Tkinter callback Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\xx\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__     return self.func(*args) TypeError: choice_sel() missing 1 required positional argument: 'index'` And I can't get to the next iteration.. I've tried to pass it with choice_sel(i) but this is not working either, so I am not sure to understand..

Comment: I did not get this error, but it is probably caused by the command under button `exit_but`. Actually I don't think you want to call the function `choice_sel` for this button, right? Could you try to change this command?